File.Copy method opens a File Explorer window
Using File.Copy within a Form, works as expected, except it open a File Explorer window as well as doing the copy and makes the new window the focus.
Anyone know how to stop this behavior?
Develop system versions:
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022
Version 17.10.3
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.10.3+35013.160
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.04084

Installed Version: Community

Visual C++ 2022   00482-90000-00000-AA398
Microsoft Visual C++ 2022

ASP.NET and Web Tools   17.10.341.11210
ASP.NET and Web Tools

Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   17.10.341.11210
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0

C# Tools   4.10.0-3.24312.19+771f269b3abcbbd991f05becf8fe5e991d24b0c1
C# components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Debugging Tools for Windows   10.0.26100.1
Integrates the Windows Debugger functionality (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=223405) in


It is the behavior of FileSystem.CopyFile().  I'll randomly guess you are working with a library that decided that File.Copy() should be "better".  Use Debug > Break All while a copy of a large file takes place and look at the call stack.

Good idea to collect more info, thanks Hans! As always, if I get to the root of the problem and solve it, I will post details.
